# Showing $u = \phi_\epsilon * u,$ ie Function Equals Convolution with Function

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

My question is the following:

Starting with the mean value property for harmonic $u \in C^2(\Bbb R^3)$, ie
$$u(x) = {1 \over {4\pi R^2}} \int_{\partial B_R(x)}u(y) dy,$$
deduce that if $\phi \in C_0^\infty (\Bbb R^3)$ has total integral $\int_{\Bbb R^3} \phi(x)dx = 1$ and is radial $\phi(x) = \psi(|x|),$ $\psi \in C_0^\infty (\Bbb R^3),$ then $u = \phi_\epsilon * u,$ where $*$ is convolution and $\phi_\epsilon(x) = \epsilon^{-3}\phi(x/\epsilon)$.

I am not far away from this (I showed that, for not necessarily harmonic $u$ then the equality is true in the limit (for not necessarily radial $\phi$), but I can't work out how to do this. Some hints would be most appreciated!

(Please don't just say the answer if you know, as this does not help me; please give a hint!)

Thank you! :)

Comment: $$(\phi_\epsilon\ast u)(x) = \int \phi_\epsilon(y) u(x+y)\,dy.$$ (We can use $u(x+y)$ instead of $u(x-y)$ due to $\phi_\epsilon (-y) = \phi_\epsilon(y)$.) Spherical coordinates.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't really help. Had a similar thing before...

Comment: Can I take a supporting ball for $\phi$ (not 100% sure what that is...) and then say that the integral inside this is then also $1$?

Comment: If by supporting ball you mean a ball containing the support of $\phi$, then yes. You need to use the radiality of $\phi$ and the mean value property of $u$ (you're probably aware of that, but let me add some extra emphasis on that).

Comment: By the way, $\epsilon$ is mostly a distraction here. You can work with $\phi$ itself, and include $\epsilon$ later (since $\phi_\epsilon$ has all the same properties as $\phi$). Suggestion: observe that $$u(x)\psi(R)  = {1 \over {4\pi R^2}} \int_{\partial B_R(x)} \phi(x-y) u(y) dy $$ and integrate over $R$,   after rearranging this formula in a more convenient way.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks, but I still can't quite get it. The MVP integral is over a surface but the total integral for $\phi$ is over a volume. The only theorem that I know for such is the divergence theorem, but I doubt that that would help here; alternatively, could I do something like
$$"\int_{\Bbb R^3} dV = \int_0^\infty dr \int_{\partial B_r(x)} dy"$$
where the $r$ is measured with $x$ at its centre?

Comment: @900sit-upsaday I can't actually see where you got that formula from... how do you get the $\phi$ inside the $\partial B_R(x)$ integral? (We don't necessarily have the MVP for $\phi$...)

Comment: When $y\in \partial B_R(x)$, we have $|x-y|=R$, and therefore $\phi(x-y)=\psi(R)$. Which is a constant factor that comes out of integral.

Comment: @SmileySam The splitting of the integral into an integral over $r$ and for each $r$ the sphere of radius $r$ is the point of the spherical coordinates (and I didn't intend that you go farther than that and use the whole family of angles, that would just make things less obvious).

Comment: I think I've got it, thank you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>I suppose enough time   passed since the comment exchange   that the answer can be posted without spoiling the fun.</sup>

The scaling factor $\epsilon$ is mostly a distraction here. You can work with $\phi$ itself, and include $\epsilon$ later (since $\phi_\epsilon$ has all the same properties as $\phi$).  Observe that 
$$u(x)\psi(R)  = {1 \over {4\pi R^2}} \int_{\partial B_R(x)}\psi(R) u(y)\, dy = 
{1 \over {4\pi R^2}} \int_{\partial B_R(x)} \phi(x-y) u(y) dy $$ 
because when $y\in \partial B_R(x)$, we have $|x-y|=R$, and therefore $\phi(x-y)=\psi(R)$.

Then multiply both sides by $4\pi R^2$ and integrate over $R$. On the right you get the convolution. On the left you get $u(x)$ multiplied by the integral of $\psi$, which is $1$.

Comment: Thank you. (Only just seen this answer - I was camping for a week!)